# how to get column headers and return to text list

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get a list of column header on the data grid. I have the issue that I can get text from the list of element on protractor. The return value always are promise and I don't know on Protractor how to get text on these promise before continue the next steps.

```js
function getcolumnheaderlist(columnheader){
 var textlist = [];
  
 var promiselist = element.all(by.css('thead[role="rowgroup"] tr th a')).map(function (elmt) {
    return elmt.getText(); 
  });
  
  promiselist.then(function (array) {
  textlist.push(array);
  });
  
  console.log(textlist);  
}
```

As my code above, the console alway print out empty. How I can force the action "get text" excute before printing out on console?

Comment: The execution of the script happens asynchronously. This means that the `promiselist` is getting used even before it's value is getting set. Try feeding the result of the first piece of code directly to the second.-
`element.all(by.css('thead[role="rowgroup"] tr th a')).map(function (elmt)
 {
    return elmt.getText(); 

  }).then(function(array){
textlist.push(array);
})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the result or the resolve promises on the console, you need to put `console.log()` *into `then()` function*:

```
promiselist.then(function (headers) {
    console.log(headers);
});
```